# Internationalization(Number formatting "num.toLocaleString()") not working for chrome

Tags: javascript, internationalization

i want do number formatting in Javascript.. and i use the following method
num.toLocaleString() which will work for Firefox, IE but doesnt work for Google Chrome..
Wat i need to add for it work in chrome browser.

Comment: Also see this [link](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1797).

Comment: you should close this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `toLocaleString()` method is by definition implementation-dependent: it uses the implementation locale, such as browser locale. So if I were looking at your page that uses the method, I would see numbers formatted according to Finnish or English locale, depending on which browser I’m using.

What you want is localization by the locale of the *page*, and for this you need something else. In simple cases you might code it yourself, but number formatting is in general complicated, making it reasonable to use a library, such as [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize). Check out the compact source of a simple [demo](http://bytelevelbooks.com/code/javascript/numberdemo.html). In Globalize, you use [standard language codes](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) when specifying the locale.

Comment: See the [relevant bug on V8's bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1034).

Answer (score 3):

Internationalization is always challenging and unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a consistent/pervasive solution to it. Your best bet is to use a 3rd party library to take care of things for you.
We rely heavily on googles closure library, which has some pretty powerful i18n (internationalization) tools. Take a look at http://www.daveoncode.com/2009/11/26/goog-i18n-numberformat-formatting-number-locale-string/ for an example of how to use it. In the end, it becomes as easy as:

```
// define italian number format symbols 
goog.i18n.NumberFormatSymbols = goog.i18n.NumberFormatSymbols_it_IT; 

// create new decimal formatter (PERCENT, CURRENCY, SCIENTIFIC are options)
formatter = new goog.i18n.NumberFormat(goog.i18n.NumberFormat.Format.DECIMAL);

// view formatted and localized string
alert(formatter.format(15650.579));
```

If you are new to closure, don't worry. It's not hard to get set up and has a multitude of excellent helper classes that you may find useful.
http://code.google.com/closure/library/docs/gettingstarted.html

Comment: You link talks about "using the default locale", does closure actually detect the users locale and select the appropriate number formats? Or is the default locale always the same?

Comment: Google's internationalization tools are static. There is no way to detect the language at run time and select the translation to use. 

That said, look in 'numberformatsymbols.js' and you will see:
`goog.i18n.NumberFormatSymbols = goog.i18n.NumberFormatSymbols_en;`

in otherwords, it defaults to English. Right after this you will find:
`if (goog.LOCALE == 'aa') {
  goog.i18n.NumberFormatSymbols = goog.i18n.NumberFormatSymbols_aa;
}`

If you look in 'base.js'
`goog.LOCALE = 'en';  // default to en`

this is a compile-time define statement to control the language to use

Comment: One other thing. If you need dynamic language capabilities, there are other tools which exist. Check out [http://jsgettext.berlios.de/](http://jsgettext.berlios.de/) to perform the dynamic translation and [https://github.com/AndyStricker/gettext-javascript](https://github.com/AndyStricker/gettext-javascript) to scan your source to find translatable strings. You should familiarize yourself with how [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html) works

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript internationalization support is quite poor (as you have discovered).
You might take a look at https://github.com/jquery/globalize
It handles number formatting, and also dates, times, currencies.

Comment: jQuery globalize appears to have changed significantly since you wrote your comment. Currently (2014) only date formatting is supported

Answer (score 0):

A bit of voodoo can implement your own number formatting. You could build this into String.prototype, but I didnt want that, since its localized.

```
function reverse(str) {
    return str.split('').reverse().join(''); 
}

function num2str(num) {
    var str = num+"";
    // european
    // return reverse(reverse(str.replace('.',',')).replace(/\d{3}/g,'$&.').replace(/\.$/,''));
    // american
    return reverse(reverse(str).replace(/\d{3}/g,'$&,').replace(/\,$/,''));
}
```

and then its

```
> console.log(25000.45)
> 25,000.45
```

Comment: ehm, limited to two digits behind the comma