# Insert whitespace after every 3 character in a string Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to display a price in a format like

```
7
70 
700
700 000
70 000
700 000
7 000 000 etc
```

The problem is that I receive the price from json file, so it's always a string.

What I want is to convert that price string into the desired format by RegEx.

1. We invert the price `7000000 = 0000007`
2. We put a whitespace after 3rd character in the inverted string `000 000 7`
3. Then we invert the string again and get a normal price format `7 000 000`

Is it possible for json data and perhaps there is a more correct way to go? Didn't find any working examples.

Comment: You should check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript.

Comment: "*The problem is that I receive the price from json file, so it's always a string.*" This is incorrect. JSON [supports numbers](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 7):

You could use a regex to do so:

```
function numberWithSpaces(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
}
```

Or convert it to a number then use `num.toLocaleString()`, which will automatically convert it.

Taken from [Adding space between numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637051/adding-space-between-numbers)