# CSS: style text of input field

Tags: css, input

Kinda solved...

It is not possible with css. If you want to check out the project (currently only working in portrait) here is the [link](https://s.codepen.io/dreitzner/debug/ERjqoW/VJkxxVxgaWPk)

I am currently rebuilding the Google calculator as a pwa.

I noticed in the app that if I put in more than 3 numbers there will be a space for every 1000x step.

```
123456789 => 123 456 789
```

Is there a way to do that with pure css? Like every `:nth(3)` from the right `padding-right:.5rem`.

If not possible I will use js.

Comment: I had the same question before and googled, seems not possible if only using css

Comment: That would be sad ;)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/ try it

Comment: Just read that article... would be a nice proposal.

Comment: you could make your input transparent and use js to create a separate element for every digit for displaying your number, and then you can use `nth(3)` to add margins to your digits

Comment: Yes,that was about what I thought I'd do. But I found this plugin, that works with css selectors :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this using css only as you will need to read the input and modify it.

You'll need javascript to achieve this, for example : [Adding space between numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637051/adding-space-between-numbers)

Comment: Thank you. I know, with js, this would be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Martin is right, you need to use a Javascript plugin like https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/