# LocalString method for german currency?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var n = (1223578.00).toLocaleString('de-DE');
```

Should be -> "1.223.578,00", but the output is: 1.223.578 (the decimal places are missing)

Whats wrong ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">var amount= '{{currency1}}';</script>
```

this is a filled form from SQL, currency1 = 1223578.00

How can I use this, with this placeholders?

Comment: Numbers do not have significant digits. That is your issue. Look at the options in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the minimumFractionDigits property to your desired number of digits.

```
var n = (1223578.00).toLocaleString('de-DE',{ minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
```

Produces: 1.223.578,00

The above function may not work on all browsers. To ensure the same result on all browsers, you can manually create the string as follows:

Modified From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16157942/4347337

```
function DelocaleString(x, sep, grp, dec) {
  //add decimals
  var y = x.toFixed(dec);
  //strip decimals
  var x_integer = y.split('.')[0];
  var x_fraction = y.split('.')[1];
  var x_fractionString = "";
  if (dec > 0) {
    x_fractionString = ',' + x_fraction;
  }
  var sx = ('' + x_integer).split('.'),
    s = '',
    i, j;
  sep || (sep = ' '); // default seperator
  grp || grp === 0 || (grp = 3); // default grouping
  i = sx[0].length;
  while (i > grp) {
    j = i - grp;
    s = sep + sx[0].slice(j, i) + s;
    i = j;
  }
  s = sx[0].slice(0, i) + s;
  sx[0] = s;
  return sx.join('.') + x_fractionString
}
```

**Example**

```js
$().ready(function() {
  $('#convertBtn').click(function() {
    ConvertNumber();
  });
});

function ConvertNumber() {
  var input = $('#in').val();
  if ($.isNumeric(input)) {
    $('#out').val(DelocaleString(+input, '.', 3, 2));
  } else {
    $('#out').val('Input is not a number!');
  }
}

function DelocaleString(x, sep, grp, dec) {
  //add decimals
  var y = x.toFixed(dec);
  //strip decimals
  var x_integer = y.split('.')[0];
  var x_fraction = y.split('.')[1];
  var x_fractionString = "";
  if (dec > 0) {
    x_fractionString = ',' + x_fraction;
  }
  var sx = ('' + x_integer).split('.'),
    s = '',
    i, j;
  sep || (sep = ' '); // default seperator
  grp || grp === 0 || (grp = 3); // default grouping
  i = sx[0].length;
  while (i > grp) {
    j = i - grp;
    s = sep + sx[0].slice(j, i) + s;
    i = j;
  }
  s = sx[0].slice(0, i) + s;
  sx[0] = s;
  return sx.join('.') + x_fractionString
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" style="max-width:350px;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="in" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Input</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="in" placeholder="Allowable formats: 123.456789, 123456789">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="out" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Output</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="out" placeholder="Formatted Number" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button class="btn btn-default" id="convertBtn">Convert Number</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Tested in Chrome 42.0 and IE 11

Comment: Good answer, though it doesn't seem to be supported on Safari https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: Thanks :-) it doesnt matter that it doesnt work with safari, because I use this for the tool "wkhtmltopdf"

Comment: @Brino ive edit my question, because im not use numbers, i use a Placeholder for wkhtmltopdf

Comment: Should work the same. If it is a string, just convert it to a number using Number() first then apply the same formulas