# how to get value of HTML element via .load via cross domain using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I get vaule of HTML element via .load function via cross domain?
The .load function works perfect, but I don't know how to rich value of single element?

HTML code from I want to get values:

```
<div class="temeratura">
<ul id="temperatura_lista">
    <li id="temp_Sypialnia" value="22.25">Temp. Sypialnia: 22.25</li>
    <li id="temp_MalyPokoj" value="19.75">Temp. Mały pokój: 19.75</li>
    <li id="temp_Salon" value="23.00">Temp. Salon: 23.00</li>
</ul>
```

My JS on other HTML page on other server (it works):

```
<script>
$( '#new-tempSypialnia' ).load( "http://some.address.com/index.html #temp_Sypialnia("value")" );
</script>
```

Comment: If I could use PHP then won't be a problem, but I can't. Is any solution to use js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, `value` property may set `22.25` to `22` , see `console` at jsfiddle , where *`22`* returned by `element.val()` , `element[0].value` , and `element.prop("value")` . `22.25` returned by `element.data("value")` from `html` `data-*` attribute.

Try

html

```
<!-- added `data-value` attributes , 
     having same `value` as `value` attributes ,
     to maintain same `data-value` when processed 
-->
<div class="temeratura">
<ul id="temperatura_lista">
  <li id="temp_Sypialnia" data-value="22.25" value="22.25">Temp. Sypialnia: 22.25</li>
  <li id="temp_MalyPokoj" data-value="19.75" value="19.75">Temp. Mały pokój: 19.75</li>
  <li id="temp_Salon" data-value="23.00" value="23.00">Temp. Salon: 23.00</li>
</ul>
```

js

```
$("#new-tempSypialnia")
.load("http://some.address.com/index.html #temp_Sypialnia #temp_Sypialnia"
, function(data) {
      var val = $(data).find("#temp_Sypialnia");

      // console.log("`elem.data('value')`:", val.data("value")
      //            , "`elem.val()`:", val.val()
      //            , "`elem[0].value`:", val[0].value); 

      var result = val.data("value");          
      alert(result);
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ckLv2eub/

See

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) , at `complete` callback

[How to handle floats and decimal separators with html5 input type number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303940/how-to-handle-floats-and-decimal-separators-with-html5-input-type-number)