# Angular tells me floats are not numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, floating-point, numbers

Angular highlights the text box with red if a non-integer number is used.

```js
(function()
 {
     var app = angular.module('example', []);

     app.controller('InputController', function()
      {
   this.number = '';
      }
     );
 })();
```

```html
<html ng-app="example">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-controller="InputController as ctl" ng-submit="inputForm.$valid">
  <input type="number" step="0.001" pattern="(-|\+)?\d*\.?\d+" ng-model="ctl.number">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

If I set the `step` to, for example, `0.001`, then it will highlight red when I put anything with more than three decimal places, e.g. `9.1234`.

If I put the pattern `(-|\+)?\d*\.?\d+`, that changes nothing.

Combining step with pattern does not fix my problem.

How can I get it to accept anything that's a number, not just integers, and only numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle floats and decimal separators with html5 input type number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303940/how-to-handle-floats-and-decimal-separators-with-html5-input-type-number)

Comment: Not an angular problem. It's a html5 input number behaviour

Comment: `pattern` or `ng-pattern` with `\d+(\.\d+)?`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude The related question says `number` allows decimals. So I suspect this is an angular problem.

Comment: None of the answers on the dupe answer my question. Thanks for trying, though.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options available either set the step size, this will up to *n* decimal places to be valid.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="ctl.number" step="0.01">
```

or do as [Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025923/tushar) suggested and validate it yourself with `ng-pattern`

Comment: Thanks  for taking the time to answer. Adding a step doesn't allow any number, for example, your step doesn't allow 0.0001. ng-pattern (or pattern) doesn't stop the input box from turning red.

Comment: for a quick fix you can just make the step size really tiny `step="0.00000000000000001"` but that isn't the correct answer long term