# How to allow only digits to be entered into an input[type="number"] field?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have an input field in which the user should only be able to enter digits `[0-9]`.

```js
document.getElementById("integer").addEventListener('input', restrictToInteger);
function restrictToInteger() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="integer" />
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/838pa8hv/)**

The problem is this: When I enter a number (eg. `1234`) and then press dot (`.`), + or - the content of the input field is automatically deleted by the browser (value is set to "" = empty string). But why? Changing the type from `number` to `text` seems to fix the problem. But then I lose the up/down arrow functionality of the input field. Any ideas?

Comment: not happening in the demo. The input isn't clearing on entering dot

Comment: Verified JSFiddle in chrome, the content of input field is not cleared.

Comment: Pressing `.` twice, however, does.

Comment: Maybe you need to enter a comma in your locale?

Comment: invalid values do not return the string with input number

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly what exactly do want should happen ?

Comment: why use js at all? the text field already doesn't support non-numerics.

Comment: I don't want the input to dissapear when dot is entered. Just to prevent any input except digits.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly what browser does it disappear?

Comment: @frederick99: Not quite. You can for instance enter thousand separator sings.

Comment: @epascarello: I tried Chrome and Firefox. Same problem.

Comment: does it for + and - too

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: You are right. It does also delete the content then. :-/

Comment: @JennyO'ReillyAccording to the w3c specs `[...]The value attribute, if specified and not empty, must have a value that is a valid floating-point number.[...]`, so you can only get `this.value` if it is valid. It is up to the browser how to report an invalid input. [4.10.5.1.9 Number state (type=number)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29).

Comment: @t.niese: Good find. It then also says this: `The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the element is not a valid floating point number, then set it to the empty string instead.`

Comment: Which is my my original comment said "invalid values do not return the string with input number" ;)

Comment: It is not the browser that clears it. It is you, with your `this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')`. Just add a `console.log(this.value)` or `alert(this.value)` before that line, to see what's happening as you type each character.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: You are absolutely right. `this.value` is an empty string (however the field does contain a value) as it is not a valid value. Working with that value destroys the content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML 4 has an **event** called `onkeypress`. With that attribute we can do this without using additional JS:

```html
<input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
```

Here digits from `0` to `9` are allowed using the `event.charCode` from  `48` to `57`.

Comment: FYI: The `onkeypress` event is now deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event

Answer (score 4):

I think the reason that the browser clean the input value it is because a string with two dots it is not a number.

**Some corrections about your code:**

You need to change your expression regular if you want to accept number with decimal part. Now, you are only express that you want to accept digits [0-9] and no more chars.

To accomplish want you want, you need to change `/[^\d]/g` to `/[^\d.]/g`.

```js
document.getElementById("integer").addEventListener('input', restrictToInteger);

function restrictToInteger()
{
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="integer" />
```

**HOWEVER:** If you define your input as number type, the regular expression is not needed. So, you just need to define the input like this and should your to your case:

```html
<input type="number" id="integer" />
```

**[THE SOLUTION]**

To fully meet your needs, I came with a solution that catch the keydown event of the input and check if there is any '.' on the input. If yes, I prevent the char to go to the input.

```js
document.getElementById("integer").addEventListener('keydown', restrictToInteger);
var lastCodeWasDot = false;
function restrictToInteger(e)
{
   var inputValue = document.getElementById("integer").value;
   var isDot = false;
   var isDot = (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 110) || (e.charCode && e.charCode == 190);
   console.log(e.keyCode);
   if(isDot && (inputValue.indexOf(".") > -1 || inputValue == "" || lastCodeWasDot)) {
       e.preventDefault();
   }
   lastCodeWasDot = isDot;
   
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="integer" />
```

*Explaning the solution*:

The line of code `var isDot = (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 110) || (e.charCode && e.keyCode == 190) || false;` is needed because **cross browser compatibility**.

I don't now why but if you try to get the value from an input number type in the firefox, and if the value finishes with a dot, the value that you will get will be without the last dot of the input. To fix that, I needed to add the variable `lastCodeWasDot` to fix this issue.

> **NOTE:** The number input can accept floating point numbers, including negative symbols and the e or E character (check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706611/why-does-the-html-input-with-type-number-allow-the-letter-e-to-be-entered-in) post)

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly I put a more extensive answer. Please fill free to ask if you have more questions

Comment: The problem is that simply setting type='number' still allows the user to enter thousands separator sign (eg. the comma) into the field. I want the user only to be able to input digits. Nothing else.

Comment: But you can still enter thousands of dots. Not what OP wants. :-)

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly Now I think this solves your problem. Can you check if I really understand you problem and solve it?

Comment: In Firefox I can enter anything I want. Even letters. So it does not work for me. :-(

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly Can you test now and check if it is working on firefox as well?

Comment: Unfortunately it still enables me to enter anything I want in Firefox.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly Finally I think that I solve the firefox issue. Can you check please if everything is ok now?

Comment: @RicardoRocha for me, also using Firefox, I can still enter letters. It doesn't stop me it just adds a red outline (which is pretty cool).

Comment: @RicardoRocha: Like DasBeasto said, I can still enter letters in Firefox.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly Sorry about the delay. I made some changes that I Now I think that will really will work. Another think is that the input considers that the char "e" is a number (maybe to represent the 
exponential number). I will put another solution  to only accept dots and numbers bettween [1-9]

Comment: @RicardoRocha: Thanks for all the effort. I tested the "[THE SOLUTION]" version. In Firefox I can still enter letters into the input field. Btw. I dropped this approach. Now I restrict the input as good as possible and validate the input when the user leaves the field. I also switched from type="number" to type="text", as in that case the browsers don't mess with the entered value.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answers of [Alexandru-Ionut Mihai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46470574/434742) and [natchiketa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16680098/434742) I created the following solution:

```js
document.getElementById("integer").addEventListener("input", allowOnlyDigits);

function allowOnlyDigits() {  
  if (this.validity.valid) {
    this.setAttribute('current-value', this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, ""));
  }
  this.value = this.getAttribute('current-value');
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="integer" />
```

On input the value is checked for validity. If it is valid, all non-digits are removed and the value is stored in a custom attribute of the element. If the value is not valid, the previous value is restored.

**Notes:**

- The RegEx-replace is required only for Internet Explorer as it allows you to enter `,` or `.` at the end of a number.
- Tested in IE, Edge, Chrome and Firefox
- Chrome still allows you to enter a `+` before and one `,` after the number.
- I found one issue: If you initialize the field with a value, the value is lost when you first hit an invalid char on the keyboard.
- Another issue: You can't enter a negative number.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem was your input type. Change it to `text` and it should work !

```js
function validate(e) {
    var charCode = e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode
    if (!(charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57)) {
        if(!(charCode>=37 && charCode<=40))
            if(charCode!=8 && charCode!=46)
            return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="integer" pattern="[0-9]"
onkeydown="return validate(event)"/>
```

Comment: I know that it works with type='text' as mentioned at the end of the question. ;-)

Comment: The arrow key functionality is lost when using this approach. Although I know it can be easily simulated using js.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly I've updated my answer, sorry I had missed your last line

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly navigate meaning ?

Comment: Sorry. What I mean is that you can no longer use the arrow keys for instance to move the cursor within the field.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly the cursor is moving just fine when I'm testing. Is it not working on your system ?

Comment: At least not in Firefox. I haven't tried any other browser yet. Edit: In Chrome it works.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly finally got it to work in firefox, updated my answer !

Comment: I can now navigate in the field using the arrow keys, but I can't delete anything in the field using the backspace or delete keys.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155520/discussion-between-mrid-and-jenny-oreilly).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your requirement by `copying` the **old** value of input and using `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` methods in order to store the values.

```js
function myFunction(input){
  input.setAttribute('current-value',"");
  input.oninput=function(){  
      let currentValue=input.getAttribute('current-value');
      if(input.value!='' || (currentValue>=1 && currentValue<=9))
        input.setAttribute('current-value',input.value);
      input.value=input.getAttribute('current-value');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" oninput="myFunction(this)"/>
<input type="number" oninput="myFunction(this)"/>
<input type="number" oninput="myFunction(this)"/>
<input type="number" oninput="myFunction(this)"/>
<input type="number" oninput="myFunction(this)"/>
```

Comment: Nice. Any way to implement a more modular solution so that it can be applied to any number of input fields not needing a global variable?

Comment: This however doesn't let you delete entered value :)

Comment: @Walk: Right. :-D

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly, I implemented a more modular solution so that it can be applied to any number of input fields, using a `hashtable`

Comment: Not what I was thinking about. :-) It would be nice to add the old value as an attribute to the same field. So that you need no extra JavaScript variables at all.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly you can save it like this `this.setAttribute('oldValue', '123');` I agree, this is a simpler solution.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly, I updated my answer using `input` attributes.

Comment: Nice it seems to work. Thanks. One last idea: I think it is better to create an event handler that does the job for one field and then attach that event handler to all fields. This way you no longer need any array.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai still selecting all input and deleting it doesn't work (or using backspace it leaves one digit).

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly, have a look now.

Comment: I found another problem with this solution. :-) When I enter a number (eg. 1234), select the entire using SHIFT-key (or Ctrl+A) and try to delete it, the number can't be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I would switch to a `cancelable` event like `keydown`.
That way you can prevent the character from being typed in the first place:

```js
var cancelEvent = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
},
restrictToInteger = function restrictToInteger(e) {
    var acceptableInput = /[0-9]/g,
        clipboardKeys = /[zxcv]/ig,
        field = e.key || e.char,
      isClipboardOperation = (clipboardKeys.test(field) && e.ctrlKey),
        inputIsAcceptable = field ? (
            acceptableInput.test(field)
            || field.length > 1
            || isClipboardOperation
        ) : true;

    if (!inputIsAcceptable) {
        cancelEvent(e);
    }
},
ensureIntegerValueOnPaste = function ensureIntegerValueOnPaste(e) {
 var data = e.clipboardData || e.dataTransfer,
    text = data.getData('text'),
        int = parseInt(this.value + text, 10);

    if (isNaN(int)) {
        cancelEvent(e);
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            e.target.value = int;
        }, 0);
    }
},
input = document.getElementById("integer");

input.addEventListener('keydown', restrictToInteger);
input.addEventListener('drop', ensureIntegerValueOnPaste);
input.addEventListener('paste', ensureIntegerValueOnPaste);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="integer" />
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/838pa8hv/2/

Disclaimers:

- Only tested in Chrome.
- The test for `field.length > 1` is to catch non-numeric keys that are valid as the up/down arrows have a value of `ArrowUp` and `ArrowDown` respectively. This also allows for keys like `Shift` (or `Home`, `Backspace`, `Delete`, etc.) to be pressed as well.

**Edit**:
To handle pastes (and drops), you can do the same thing in those respective events. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/838pa8hv/9/) and code snippet above.

**Edit**:
If the expected usability is to be able to paste/drop partial numbers into the field **and** to not allow negative integers, then you can just change how `int` is defined in the `ensureIntegerValueOnPaste` function. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/838pa8hv/10/) and code snippet above.

Comment: I found a bug. :-) You can copy/paste letters into the field.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly Updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks! If I enter "1" I can't paste a "2" behind it. Paste seems to overwrite the entire content. Is this intended?

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly I would consider that intended behavior as I don't think most people are not going to type a portion of the number and then paste or drop in the rest. Typically, I would think they'll either paste/drop or just type the number in. You can change the behavior to allow partial pasting/dropping though by *removing the entire falsy clause* from the `isNaN(int)` conditional. I didn't like that as `-` could wind up in the middle  or the end of the field and that... seemed silly.

Comment: I understand. Nevertheless the expected usability is exactly that: pasting a portion of the number. One thing though: You can't enter a negative value, can you? (however the question originally didn't ask for it)

Comment: When you paste something into the field, it is always added to the end. That's a strange behaviour I think.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `oninput`, the `<input>` element first calls its internal methods to handle the value. This prevents your function from seeing any actual erroneous characters, namely `e+-.` - all used by JavaScript to format numbers.

You can see this by adding `console.log` calls before and after changing `this.value`.

```
console.log(this.value);
this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
console.log(this.value);
```

There is never any difference!

If you try, for example:

```
console.log(this.value);
this.value+=1; // or *=2 for numerical fun
console.log(this.value);
```

you can see a difference.

So your function is hastening the normal internal calls `<input type='number'/>` would normally make when handling illegal input.

Can't quite see why the field is left blank and not `1` though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expression, you can use `parseFloat()` function. Your input type remains unchanged, there are still "arrows" to increase/decrease number and also it makes sure that your input will not start with zero.

```js
document.getElementById("integer").addEventListener('input', restrictToInteger);
function restrictToInteger() {
  this.value = parseFloat(this.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="integer" />
```

Comment: This does not work as we already found out with the help of the others that the browser automatically clears the value of the field if it considers it to be not a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the value is not a number and then stop user.

```js
document.getElementById("integer").addEventListener('input', restrictToInteger);

function restrictToInteger(e)
{
  if(isNaN(e.data)){
     alert("only numbers allowed");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="integer" />
```

Comment: But if you enter a valid number and then hit a dot, the content of the field is deleted by the browser.