# Force to use point instead of comma for decimal separator in HTML5 number input tag

Tags: html

I have some problem in html5 input tag.

The tag is `<input type="number" step="0.01">` and in fields where my application show some decimals i get some stuff like "1,194", but it should be "1.194".

I've changed language of my chrome browser to English(ES) and it works perfectly. But when i use another language, the comma appear but I'd like to use the number input with correct display of decimals.
I've search for this problem in the internet but their workaround is use `input type="text"` instead but i want to use number input to display and manipulate with number.

So, Is there a way to force browsers to use a decimal point in the number input? (Not change the language of browser).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303940/how-to-handle-floats-and-decimal-separators-with-html5-input-type-number

Comment: i think both of them currently haven't solution to handle dot or comma in number input field.