# Adding a prefix and commas in a Javascript counter

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript counter that I want to add a dollar sign "$" to the front of and I'd like for there to be commas to help with legibility as the counter climbs to 3,000,000.

The counter is a part of a template module (windy-counter). Here is the code from the page the counter is displaying on:

```
<div  class ="windy-counter" ##>[zt_counter_box iconSize="14" from="0" to="3000000" unit="+" unitPos="after" updown="up" speed="3000" countColor="#00aeef" contentColor="#747474" border="no" bdColor="#e0dede" column="3"]Operating Costs Saved[/zt_counter_box]</div>
```

Not sure if I can achieve this here or if I need to dive in to the Java code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with windy counter, but it should be possible. However, you haven't given enough context for us to help you. Can you produce an [mcve]?

Comment: You might want to look at [*Internationalization(Number formatting “num.toLocaleString()”) not working for chrome*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906567/internationalizationnumber-formatting-num-tolocalestring-not-working-for-c).

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying to convert a number in javascript to a formatted string as you posted then you can make use of `toLocaleString` function and then append `$` at the beginning.

`formattedNumber = "$" + num.toLocaleString();`

**Complete Code:**

```js
var num = 3000000;
formattedNumber = "$" + num.toLocaleString();
console.log(formattedNumber);

// OR

var num = 3000000;
formattedNumber = num.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'});
console.log(formattedNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest solution would be if *toLocaleString* could be combined with *toFixed*, but that doesn't seem practical.

*toLocaleString* can be used to format numbers according to different languages (the term "locale" is a misnomer) and currencies. However, while ECMA-402 (on which the options to *toLocaleString* are based) uses the established [ISO 3217 codes](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/currency_codes.htm) for currencies, it allows implementations to vary their representation so users may get standard codes for some (e.g. FJD for Fiji dollar), non–standard letters and symbols for a few (e.g. NZ$ for New Zealand dollar), and just symbols for others (e.g. $ for US dollar) (see [EMCA-402 §6.3](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/3.0/index.html#sec-currency-codes)).

So users are still left wondering which currency a symbol represents for currencies used in multiple countries, e.g.

1. Is $ for US, Australian, New Zealand or Fiji dollar (and many others)?
2. Is £ for British, Lebanese or Egyptian pound (and many others)?

If you have an application that you want to accurately reflect currencies in a format familiar to the user:

1. Prefix the number with the correct ISO 3217 code
2. Specify the language as *undefined*
3. Format the number using the required number of decimal places.

E.g.

```js
var num = 3000000;
var currencies = ['USD','NZD','FJD','EUR','GBP','EGP','LBP','MRO','JPY']

console.log('toString variants (the first 3 are all dollars)\n');
currencies.forEach(function(c){
  console.log(c + ': ' + num.toLocaleString(undefined, {style: 'currency', currency: c}));
});

console.log('Consistent with ISO 4217\n');
currencies.forEach(function(c) {
  console.log(c + ': ' + c + num.toLocaleString(undefined,
   {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}));
});
```

Using the ISO currency code means all currencies are treated equally and there's no confusion over symbology.

There are only two countries that don't use decimal currencies: Madagascar (1 ariary = 5 iraimbilanja) and Mauritania (1 ouguiya = 5 khoums). *toLocaleString* doesn't do anything special with those currencies, so you'll need special handling if you wish to accommodate their minor units. You may want to support older (or ancient) non–decimal currencies like the old British pound or Greek drachma, but you'll need special handling for those too.